# Count of people doing activity by 15 min increments - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table in SQL Server which is structured like:

> ActivityName(varchar), UserId(varchar), ActivityStartTime(varchar), ActivityTimeInMinutes(smallint)

And has this sample data:

> Cooking, James, 1300, 60
>    Cleaning, James, 1400, 120
>    Sleeping, James, 1600, 90
>    Driving, Jill, 1100, 120
>    Cleaning, Jill, 1300, 30
>    Cooking, Jill, 1330, 45
>    Sleeping, Jill, 1414, 120

How can I create a table in sql that counts the number of people doing each activity in 15 minute increments, so in the above example this would be the entry for 1300-1400:

> TimePeriod, Cooking, Cleaning, Driving, Sleeping
>   1300 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0
>   1315 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0
>   1330 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 0
>   1400 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That won't be easy. You will have to create records for all time ranges 13:00-13:14, 13:15-13:30 ..., then outer join your table such that you find activities that took completely or partially place within. So you would probably convert to datetimes and compare start and end times of the generated ranges and your activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data needs to be pivoted to get the desired results. This sql assumes that you are only interested in the time, (not the date) and that the times are all formated "hhmm". So 6AM would be rendered 0600. If this is not the case, this code would need to be updated to add the extra zero.

```
-- load your test data
declare @Activity table
    (
    ActivityName varchar(50),
    UserId varchar(50),
    ActivityStartTime varchar(50),
    ActivityTimeInMinutes smallint
    )
insert into @Activity values
    ('Cooking','James','1300',60),
    ('Cleaning','James','1400',120),
    ('Sleeping','James','1600',90),
    ('Driving','Jill','1100',120),
    ('Cleaning','Jill','1300',30),
    ('Cooking','Jill','1330',45),
    ('Sleeping','Jill','1414',120)

-- populate @TimeTable with 15 min increments based on your time data
declare @TimeTable table
    (
    StartTime datetime,
    EndTime datetime
    )
declare @ActivityStartTime datetime,
        @ActivityEndTime datetime
select @ActivityStartTime =
        min(left(ActivityStartTime,2) + ':' + right(ActivityStartTime,2)),
  @ActivityEndTime =
        max(dateadd(minute,ActivityTimeInMinutes,left(ActivityStartTime,2)
        + ':' + right(ActivityStartTime,2)))
from @Activity
while @ActivityStartTime <= @ActivityEndTime
    begin
        insert into @TimeTable values
            (@ActivityStartTime,dateadd(minute,15,@ActivityStartTime))
        set @ActivityStartTime = dateadd(minute,15,@ActivityStartTime)
    end

-- pivot results
select
    replace(left(convert(varchar(8),TimePeriod,108),5),':','') TimePeriod,
    isnull(Cooking,0) Cooking,
    isnull(Cleaning,0) Cleaning,
    isnull(Driving,0) Driving,
    isnull(Sleeping,0) Sleeping
from    (
        select
            t.StartTime TimePeriod,
            a.ActivityName,
            count(a.UserID) Cnt
        from @TimeTable t
            inner join @Activity a
                on cast(left(ActivityStartTime,2) + ':' +
                    right(ActivityStartTime,2) as datetime) < t.EndTime
                and dateadd(minute,a.ActivityTimeInMinutes,
                    cast(left(ActivityStartTime,2) + ':' +
                    right(ActivityStartTime,2) as datetime)) > t.StartTime
        group by 
            t.StartTime,
            a.ActivityName
        ) t
        pivot   (
                sum(Cnt)
                for ActivityName in([Cooking],[Cleaning],[Driving],[Sleeping])
                ) p
order by TimePeriod
```

Comment: Wow.. this worked perfectly.. now to figure out why. :)

Comment: Happy to help :) Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT 
    UserId, 
    ActivityName,
    DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
        YEAR(ActivityStartTime),
        MONTH(ActivityStartTime),
        DAY(ActivityStartTime),
        HOUR(ActivityStartTime),
        (MINUTE(ActivityStartTime)/15) * 15,
        0,
        0
    ) AS ActivityStartQtrHour
    SUM(ActivityTimeInMinutes) AS ActivityDurationMinutes
GROUP BY 
    UserId, 
    ActivityName,
    DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
        YEAR(ActivityStartTime),
        MONTH(ActivityStartTime),
        DAY(ActivityStartTime),
        HOUR(ActivityStartTime),
        (MINUTE(ActivityStartTime)/15) * 15,
        0,
        0
    )
```

Not tested as there was no test data, but you should be able to follow it in any case.

Comment: This is a SQL Server 2012 solution, I should mention. It's a bit more convenient than previous versions, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Thanks so much!  The only problem I have is ActivityStartTime is a character field.. I guess I need to convert it to a datetime then?

Comment: Correct, that will give you a valid date check as well. Other than that, you could also use substrings for date parts to much the same effect.